# How to Remove root element for collection when WCF Serializes collection property

Tags: wcf, xml-serialization

I am having problem in serializing XML element, particularly removing root tag for array/ collection

```
 public Class Part
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable = false)]
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string PartNumber { get; set; }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable = false)]
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string PartName { get; set; }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable = true)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable = false)]
        public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

        [XmlElement()]
        public string[] PartDetails{ get; set; }
    }
```

wcf serializes this into

```
 <b:Part>
            <b:PartDetail xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
              <c:string>ABC</c:string>
            </b:PartDetail>
            <b:PartDetail xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
              <c:string>DEF</c:string>
            </b:PartDetail>
            <b:Description> JGHGS SGHSGH SJGHSJG</b:Description>
            <b:Id>740ead2d-84e8-4da0-9115-28dea5f0bd28</b:Id>
            <b:LastUpdated>2012-11-30</b:LastUpdated>
            <b:PartName>AAA BBB CCC DDDD</b:PartName>
            <b:PartNumber>1</b:PartNumber>
          </b:Part>
```

What I require

```
 <b:Part>
                <b:PartDetail xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">ABC</b:PartDetail>
                <b:PartDetail xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">DEF</b:PartDetail>             

                <b:Description> JGHGS SGHSGH SJGHSJG</b:Description>
                <b:Id>740ead2d-84e8-4da0-9115-28dea5f0bd28</b:Id>
                <b:LastUpdated>2012-11-30</b:LastUpdated>
                <b:PartName>AAA BBB CCC DDDD</b:PartName>
                <b:PartNumber>1</b:PartNumber>
              </b:Part>
```

I have found similar questions in SO but didn't get any definitive answer (may be didnt understand) how to use it with WCF.

Basically I want

```
<ArrayPropertyName>ABC</ArrayPropertyName>
<ArrayPropertyName>DEF</ArrayPropertyName>
<ArrayPropertyName>GHI</ArrayPropertyName>
```

instead of

```
<ArrayPropertyName>
<string> ABC</string>
<string> DEF</string>
<string> GHI</string>
</ArrayPropertyName>
```

is it possible to search and remove the tag before wcf send xml-serialized data out?

Let me know if the question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a PartDetail class to accomplish that, something like

```
public class PartDetail
{
    [XmlText()] 
    public string value;
}    

public Class Part
{

     [XmlElement("PartDetail")]
     public PartDetail[] PartDetails { get; set; }

}
```